# After getting the data from controller to view, how to send back the data to the view

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

**Controller:**

```
{
    private static string selection = String.Empty;
    dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
    public ActionResult Post(string Name)
    {
        selection = Name;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        SegmentRepository segment = new SegmentRepository();
        mymodel.listofSegments = segment.GetSegmentation();
        DynamicRepository dynamic = new DynamicRepository();
        mymodel.listofDynamic = dynamic.GetDynamicContent(selection); //After selecting the segmentation in the view it returns the required dynamic content in mymodel.listofDynamic  but does not display it in the view.
        return View(mymodel);
    }
}
```

After selecting the segmentation in the view, it returns the required dynamic content in `mymodel.listofDynamic` but does not display it in the view.

**View:**

```
<script>
    function seg() {
        var employment = document.getElementById("Employment").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
            url: '@Url.Action("Post","Home")', // Controller/View
            data: {
                //Passing data
                Name: employment //Reading text box values using Jquery
            }
        })
    }
</script>

<tr>
    <td height="100">
        <label>220</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="Employment">
            <option>---Select---</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.listofSegments)
            {      
                <option name="selectedSegment" value="@item">@item</option>
            }
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" onclick="seg()">
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="Dynamic">
            <option>---Select---</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.listofDynamic)
            {
                <option name="selectedDynamic" value="@item">@item</option>
            }// I need the data to get listed here
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="Submit1">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would need the `public ActionResult Index()` method to run again so the data in `listofDynamic` gets printed in the view. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your making an ajax call - ajax calls never redirect (the whole point of them is to stay on the same page). Make a normal submit to your `Post()` method

Answer (score 0):

In the data section of the `Ajax`, use the following:

```
data: { "name": employment }, //Pass value of employment variable as the name parameter
success: function(data) {
     alert(data); //In the success function, pass the data to be notified in the view
}
```

The above will return data from controller to view using `Ajax`.

In the same time, make a `Json` method to make it work or an `ActionResult` will also do:

```
public JsonResult GetResults(string name) //Here is the name parameter
{
   MainEntities db = new MainEntities(); //Db context

   var con = (from c in db.TableName
              where c.ColumnName == name //Pass the name parameter in the query
              select c).ToList();

   return Json(con); //Finally returns the result in Json
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to get values by Ajax you forget success and error part. 
View part:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
            url: '@Url.Action("Post","Home")', // Controller/View
            data: {
                //Passing data
                Name: employment //Reading text box values using Jquery
            },
            success:function(result){alert(result);},
            error:function(error){alert(error.responseText);}
        })
```

controller side like AT-2017 wrote JsonResult or you can return partial view/any another type.